# measurability and convergence of unconditional probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-convergence, conditional-probability

This should be simple, and with a bit of study I should get there, but I am very tired and in a need for a hand. Thanks in advance.

If $\rho$ is a probability measure over $Y$. For each $y \in Y$ there is a measure $\mu_y$ over $X$, (you can assume $X=Y=[0,1]$). If I wish to define the unconditional measure $\mu$ over $X$, $\mu(A)=\int _{y \in Y} \mu_y(A) \partial \rho$, for any $A \in \sigma_X$ ( $\sigma$-algebra can be Borel). When is $\mu$ measurable? Do I need any special condition on $\mu_y$?

If $\rho^n$ converges weakly to $\rho$, $\rho^n \Rightarrow \rho$ and $\mu_y^n \Rightarrow \mu_y$ for all $y \in Y$, does $\mu^n  \Rightarrow \mu$?

Comment: What does it mean for $\mu$ to be measurable? For the integral to make sense you need $\mu_{\cdot}(A)$ to be measurable for all measuruable $A \subseteq X$.

Comment: Yes, true, but what do I need to impose on $\mu_y$ for that to happen?

Comment: My first sentence was really a question. The second sentence was a remark. Again: $y \mapsto \mu_y(A)$ must be measurable for all $A \subseteq X$ measurable. This is what $\mu_y$ must satisfy in order for the integral to make sense.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, I did not understand what you meant, that is of course true. 
For $\mu $ to be measurable means, for instance, that $\mu^{-1}((-\infty, a))$ is borelian in $X$.

Comment: *For $μ$ to be measurable means, for instance, that $μ^{−1}((−∞,a))$ is borelian in $X$*... Whaaat? Actually, $\mu$ is defined on $\sigma_X$ the sigma-algebra on $X$, hence $μ^{−1}((−∞,a))$ is a subset of $\sigma_X$, not of $X$. You might want to explain.

Comment: Which parts of your question are not answered [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem)?

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your "whaaat" Did, by "borelian in $X$" I meant the borelians set of $X$, maybe my english isn't perfect but I think my idea is clear. Honestly, I dont see what else could it be.

Comment: You might start by reading my comment: as I tried to explain, $A=\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ cannot be a Borel subset of $X$ because $A$ is not a subset of $X$.

Comment: I see your point, I should have said a Borelians of $X$, thanks. In the links the questions are not answered. My problem is not of building the conditional probability, but of building the unconditional probability from the conditionals. It should be simpler, what I would like to know is what conditions should be imposed on $\mu_y$ for $\mu$ to be measurable.

Comment: Again: $\mu$ is a map from $\sigma_X$, which is a set of subsets of $X$, so every preimage, for instance $\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))$, is a set of subsets of $X$. But what you seem to think is that it is a subset of $X$.

Comment: And again, if I change from Borelian to Borelians, it seems, to me at least, that I know it is a set of sets of X. For some reason I changed to plural.

Comment: @xxcents You might want to read what people are explaining to you... Let me try once again: the measure $\mu$ is defined on $\sigma_X$ since, as a measure, $\mu$ associates a number to some subsets of $X$. In formula, $\mu:\sigma_X\to\mathbb R$. Thus, considering a subset $(-\infty,a)$ of $\mathbb R$, $\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ is a subset of $\sigma_X$. In formula, $\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))=\{B\in\sigma_X\mid\mu(B)\lt a\}$. To summarise, $\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))\subseteq\sigma_X$ and, to say that $\mu^{-1}((-\infty,a))$ is a Borel subset of $X$ is absurd.